# In the Netherlands, in what kind of stores do I look for everyday men's clothes?

Tags: netherlands, shopping, clothing

I've been living in Amsterdam for several months and have postponed clothes shopping for a while. Now I need to get some... so, I know there's the area famous for department stores and large brand stores, around Dam square - but I'm not in the market for something expensive and from some fancy brand. I have passed a couple of smaller stores a few times cycling around, but I haven't gone into any.

So, in which kinds of stores / which areas of the city would I look for reasonable-quality but not high-end/famous-brand men's wear (shirts and pants mostly)?

Note: I'm from Israel/Palestine, I don't dress traditionally or 'up-dress' (e.g. a proper suite would be too fancy for me) , I guess you could say that dress-wise you couldn't tell me apart from a nondescript local on the street.

Comment: The main European “fast fashion”/entry level prêt-à-porter brands (H&M, Zara, C&A…) have a presence in the Netherlands along with some lesser known brands (Peek & Cloppenburg, WE, Charles Vögele…). Primark and Zeeman are probably the cheapest. Is that what you are looking for? You can find a few of these along the Nieuwendijk, the pedestrian street parallel to the Damrak. Beyond that, there is also a kind of fashion/clothing shopping area around the Pieter Cornelisz. Hoofstraat but it's more higher-end shops, not really cheaper than De Bijenkorf.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want something specifically geared towards men, with mostly business casual wear, there is a Dutch brand called Suitable that might be a good option. It's not super-super-cheap but they have an outlet in the Hague where you can get large discounts if you buy several items of the same kind during the sales period. There are a few other options for more formal business wear as well.

Comment: @Gala; why not combine your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out [Esprit](http://www.esprit.com/storefinder?lang_code=nl&country_code=NL). They are of reasonable quality, have a great online store, and have physical shops in major Dutch cities.

Otherwise H&M or Zara are staples of budget European clothing and are worth checking out.